# Confusion in whether to store data in state or variable in react

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, use-state

I am making a full stack forum website. In frontend I go to link like this /posts/:id and get this id and use useEffect to get the forum of that id from backend . But where should I store the backend data after receiving. Should I store it in a variable or in state . The data I am receiving contains date created and all the comments. If possible , please explain the basic difference of when to store data in state and when in variable.

Comment: you can store anything in state, it wouldn't cause any issues. basic difference is: state with re-render the component, variable will not

Answer (score 1):

Because changing the state will re-render your component to present the most recent data in the view, you should keep this data in the state.
If you save this data in a variable, your component will not be updated!